# Opening Chrome detached using Ruby Watir with Chrome 76 and newer on Mac

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have a couple of ruby scripts that drive a Chrome browser. I was using Chrome 75 using this code...

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps[:chrome_options] = {detach: true}
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

which worked fine, i.e. the Chrome browser detached itself even when the script finished.

Since Chrome updated itself to Version 76.0.3809.100 this no longer works, so with all my scripts Chrome opens and closes immediately as the detachment no longer works.

I also tried this

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :chrome_options => {:detach => true }
```

but this also doesn work.

I am using Watir 6.16.5, ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 and selenium-webdrive 3.142.3

I appreciate any input how to launch a Chrome instance detached using Watir with this setup.

P.S. My current workaround: I added a 20 minute sleep at the end of each script...

Comment: If it was working with Chrome 75 and broke with 76 it is almost certainly a bug in chromedriver. If you (or someone else) can replicate the bug, `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info` will capture the exact capabilities sent to the driver, which can go into the bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver

Comment: This is what I get from Selenium after adding the logging:


2019-08-11 09:56:27 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:9516/session | {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","version":"","platform":"ANY","javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":false,"nativeEvents":false,"rotatable":false,"chromeOptions":{"detach":true}},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome"}]}}

Answer (score 1):

The Capabilities you provided indicate that detach is getting added properly in the `desiredCapabilities` section (old JSON Wire Protocol), but not the new `capabilities` section (new w3c webdriver standard protocol). When Chrome switched to v75, it turned on w3c mode by default. This almost certainly worked with Chrome 74, and did not work with Chrome 75 or 76.

This problem is a result of Watir trying (in an incorrect manner) to compensate for a long-standing Selenium problem. Once we agree on what Selenium stuff needs to look like in 4.0 (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/7378) then I'll have the time to fix up Watir so that things work the way you would expect them to.

I don't love that this is how you have to do it right now, but I just verified this works:

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_option(:detach, true)
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :options => options
```